# How to solve the problem with missing autoload_psr4.php file in Joomla?

Tags: ubuntu, npm, joomla, composer-php

I'm trying to create a Joomla-based dev env, but I'm having trouble installing Joomla.

Cloned the https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms repo

Loaded the page and it said:

[image]

Opened the Mode Details page, which looked like this:

[image]

In the root of the repo, ran

```
composer install
```

and it succeeded. Then ran

```
npm ci
```

and that succeeded as well. However, then I try to load the page, I get the error of:

> Failed opening required '/joomla-cms/administrator/cache/autoload_psr4.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')

Looked at the mentioned location and I can confirm the file does not exist. So, the error message makes sense: it complains about a missing file that is missing indeed. But I do not know why this file is missing and what should I do to resolve this issue.

I'm using Linux Ubuntu and currently I'm testing with Apache. How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: If `composer install` succeeded, what makes you think that this problem is related to Composer after all?

Comment: @NicoHaase I do not exclude that it might be related. I do not know what it is related with. So I provide as much information as possible.

Comment: cloning the repository and then loading the page is not enough. You have to follow the installation instructions for _from source_, compare [How to get a working installation from the source](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms#how-to-get-a-working-installation-from-the-source). You will also find a remark dedicated to the file in your question.

Comment: @hakre I have followed the steps the Quick Start Guide suggested. The page you have shared has an extra step to checkout to a specific branch. I have restarted the process from scratch with that in mind, but the result was the same, this file is missing. I'm not sure why is this file missing and what could I do to generate or recover it.

Comment: @hakre the page claims "Things to be aware of when pulling: Joomla creates a cache of the namespaces of its extensions in JOOMLA_ROOT/administrator/cache/autoload_psr4.php. If extensions are created, deleted or removed in git then this file needs to be recreated. You can simply delete the file and it will be regenerated on the next call to Joomla.". My problem is that I do not see Joomla generating that file despite following the steps to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: There is a file by that name at libraries/vendor/composer. But there is no such file at the place I expected it to be at

Comment: Not fluent with setting up Joomla, but how I understood the instructions (that note there) is that the file is being generated automagically. Perhaps you can trigger this by adding an extension somehow? Or scanning the source what triggers the rebuild may also shed some light (grepping that filename?). Again, not fluent with it, the instructions may be incomplete (would not be the first project with that disease), but if, then I'd assume only in little detail. Point remains in _which_ detail. It's good if you can already automate the instructions and replay from scratch, e.g. a shell script.

Comment: About the composer file: where did you expect it and why? could you elaborate?

Comment: @hakre I'm just desperately looking for any clues. This page proved to be particularly helpful: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=998314 I took that file and copied it into the administrator/cache location where it's expected (I know, it's an extremely ugly hack, but I'm just experimenting here). Now I get some different error and I think I start to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: if that's it, two things: check access to db is good with credentials (IIRC joomla throws an error if not, so this is perhaps a red herring in that thread) and second the process that executes php (and therefore php) needs to have the correct rights to write that file. Which could be obvious, but well, easy to miss if not the case (and yeah, we normally don't like that apart from a development system, deployments should work read-only for application files).

Comment: @hakre shoot. It was a permission issue. Managed to reach the installer. I removed my hacky install and starting to do it with more conventional means.

Comment: @hakre the misleading part is that I did not get an error complaining about permissions. That would have saved me from a loooooong suffering.

Comment: Put that as an answer (also with the link to the forums), perhaps also what you changed to get it running (and which distro). Great to read! (and after some time accept your answer, it won't work immediately).

Comment: @LajosArpad: That is often an optimization, and given that it does not run until fixed, do you really need an error message for diagnosis? ^^

Comment: @hakre I plan to answer this question once the solution is final and reproducible. SO will allow me to do so, because I suffered with it for two days already (okay, not quite, because the client had me to solve some other issues that did not require the dev env, but I constantly feared about the dev env issue...)

Comment: Get the budget from the client to get your dev env running first as this will help your client soooo much as you can deal with anything just much more straight forward. Those things actually can't be paid in money. So add this to your paycheck. Just saying.

Comment: @hakre apparently I do. The error I received was misleading me. Maybe others would have looked at the right place, but I can say for sure that I was focusing my research on what I am missing, what dbs to generate/download, whether some settings were off with either my Nginx or Apache (tried with both), whether I downloaded Joomla from the right place, whether npm or composer is of the wrong version. I checked literally everything, except the actual issue...

Comment: @hakre it's paid for, but I was really afraid that I will have to tell him that I will allocate an amount of time that is unreasonably high. Fortunately the other tickets were not depending on the dev env (upgrading UA -> GA4), so the lack of a dev env was not really a trouble yet, but it was something I worried about. As Nimzowitsch, the great chess player said: "Threat is stronger than the execution"

Comment: @hakre thanks for those comments, you helped me quite a lot. I have managed to solve the issue and now I'm getting further with the installation, but your stamp is definitely in the answer and future Linux users getting this exact issue should be grateful to you just as much for easing their dev env setup.

Comment: Cheers an no worries! Glad I could help. And my doing was very little compared to your work. It's just we need some support from time to time to get things done and that's how we do it. Why not leave a message as well in the Joomla forums? I mean at the end of the day, we took the hint from there^^. Now enough comments, happy if you ping me after you've placed the answer. The only thing I'm wondering - but that is pretty much a detail - how this works for read-only deployments. I think this is the reason why it's good to not show any error message as contradicting as it may sound right now.

Comment: @hakre the error message can be directed into the server logs, so even though one does not see it on the screen once loading the page, he/she can infer the error from the logs. Joomla has settings for the log path at <root>/configuration.php, which is the location one should search for the logs. If these are not set, then I suppose the logs might be at the Apache/Nginx/IIS error log location.

Comment: @LajosArpad: Yes, it _could_ but given this kind of setup is not intended (for real, e.g. production), it should not. This is hard to explain for me, but imagine a system fails there because of insufficient disk amount (free space), then you want to prevent at all cost any more i/o which includes diagnostic messages. They won't help but only distract getting back to operations. I do understand this is unfortunate for the initial setup. But most often this is an optimization that is not prematurely, but stems from (real) operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that my main OS user owned the cloned repo's folder and the **autoload_psr4.php** file was attempted to be generated by the user which loaded the page from the browser, so I needed to run this command

```
sudo chown -R arpad:www-data joomla-cms
```

and the installer started to operate as expected

[image]

That allowed the file to be created during the request that was being sent from the browser. I may have further issues down the line, but if I do, they will be of some different nature.

**I advise all Linux users to check the permissions of the folder if you face this issue. It will save you from a lot of suffering.**

EDIT

In the comment section some clarifications were asked for, which prompted me to edit this answer with further information.

I'm using Debian Linux (Ubuntu)

In my example, arpad is a sudoer user.

`joomla-cms` is the folder where Joomla is located. Since the private repo I am working with is less of a concern in our case, in the scope of this answer I'm only focusing on Joomla's repo, the things I need to do prior the unique part of the dev env's setup.

Comment: For the user-name/group-name I think it is a good idea to share which Linux distro and which webserver with it (not that everyone has the same, but when in doubt, it is easier to run the conclusions). And perhaps what the user arpad is (detail), and more importantly what the meaning of `joomla-cms` (as a relative pathname) is, e.g. webroot of the Joomla install or something it is. So that users reading it can connect it to their parts. This is normally helpful for trouble-shooting.

Comment: And take care with development setups based on git: the chown -R may contain the GIT_DIR (.git). Clearly your case is about a development setup which is private, but just in case this comment that this configuration does not fit a public setup on the interwebs. Just saying.

Comment: @hakre thanks for the comments. I have added further clarifications to the answer. As about the .git folder, we need not to worry about it, as it's only the .git folder of the Joomla repo. At the end I am manually removing it and replacing it with a more secure folder.

Comment: No worries about the .git folder, just a comment/remark. And thanks for the quick update! I didn't even realize you already answered ^^. Have fun coding.